# Localhost is not responding in XAMPP

Tags: xampp, localhost

I have installed XAMPP on my laptop, and uninstalled Skype. I've tried to change the ports. I've done almost everything, but localhost is not working. It shows a blank white page with nothing on it.

This is the page which turns out when I try to open local-host:

[image: A BLANK PAGE]

Comment: Can you include the HTML page you are serving please

Comment: @jrtapsell he is not trying to call a HTML page this should just open his root directory

Comment: If he has a file that is being served which is empty this would explain the blank page, if the server was not responding you would get a chrome error page

Comment: Which HTML Page...  Which file is empty... Please Guide me... Thank you.

Comment: @Parallax: ...what ports were changed? ... is there any potential clues (errors) in the `xampp\apache\logs\error.log`?